# How to pass parameters down to an await function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my vue.js application, I am trying to read the value of `name` that I am passing to my function. I believe this is a scope issue. Looking around, I think this could be solved with a fat arrow function?

Here is what I am using to handle a change event. Is there a way to

```
async handleChange(event, name) {
    console.log('name: ', name);  // works
    console.log('value: ', event.value);  // works

    try {
        let response = await axios.patch(`/my/path`, {
            name: event.value,  // need to get the value from name
         });

         if (response.status === 200) {
             //
         } else {
             console.error('Error: could not update. ', response);
         }
     } catch (error) {
         console.error('Error: sending patch request. ', error);
     }
}
```

I have also tried this to start:

```
handleChange: async (event, name) => {
    ...
}
```

I'm just not sure how to use a fat arrow function within the axios patch. Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: What exactly is the problem here ?

Comment: I'm trying to access the `name` value that I'm passing into the function. But, I'm not able to read it.

Comment: Are you sure the name isn't being sent? If those first two logs work then you're not running into a scoping issue...it's something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not fully clear but I guess you want to pass name as key inside of object. If so do this:

```js
let response = await axios.patch(`/my/path`, {
   [name]: event.value,
});
```

Comment: That was it. I'm kind of confused now - I was unable to get the value of `name` before. I tried your suggestion of `[name]` and I'm getting the actual value now. What do the braces do around `[name]`? Even if I named that property to `foo`, (instead of name) I was unable to get the value.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Its a shorthand for `object[key] = value`.
`const a = 'imKey';`
`const obj = {};`
`obj[a] = 1;`

`console.log(obj); // {imKey: 1}`.

This formatting is not clear, sorry

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That's exactly what I wasn't comprehending. I was getting the value of the variable right away -- but then I was losing the value and passing the literal string of "name" in my axios request. Thank you very much!